# Semi-Opaque Graphics Appear Black When Saved to PDF from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, transparency, creative-cloud

I am working in Illustrator CC with a CMYK file that has lines stroked with black at an opacity of 10%. When I save this image to a `.pdf`, the strokes turn pure black instead of being transparent. Why is this happening?

Comment: What PDF job options are you using?

Comment: I set it up "Press Quality", but I actually figured it out. I had a blending mode that seems to be incompatible  with PDFs, so I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Spot colors and some blend modes **do not** appear correct in Apple's Preview application.

This issue has **nothing** to do with the PDF. It's a problem with Preview.

Comment: That is great to know! Thanks. What do you recommend for previewing PDFs?

Comment: Acrobat or Reader.